# How to organize a single query to several sql servers?

Tags: sql-server

I need to make an inner join sql query to several SQL Servers (one is 2000 and another is 2008 R2). The query is like the following:

```
SELECT 
   k.ID, k.NAME, k.BIRTH, l.PROFILEID 
FROM 
   CUSTOMERS..REGISTRY k 
INNER JOIN
   SECURITY..USERS l ON K.ID = l.ID
```

The `CUSTOMERS..REGISTRY` is on the 2008 R2 and `SECURITY..USERS` is on the 2000 servers. The servers are situated in different networks, connected through internet. Is there any way to organize such query?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The servers are situated in different networks, connected through
>   internet.

Preferably, don't do that.

VPN and (as AceCTO suggested) linked servers if you must but if this is a query you want to run regularly, move the data. BCP it, replicate it, log ship it... just move it.

Comment: Thanks for advice, my experiments with linked servers showed that you are right

Answer (score 2):

You appear to need linked servers:

[Microsoft SQL Server Linked Servers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188279%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

You can attach the 2000 instance from the 2008 server to use in your queries, depending on the amount of data and connection speed the performance may not be acceptable.

Comment: I have some serious security concerns about trying to establish linked servers over an open internet connection.  I would make sure to secure this connection if I were going to use this.